# AS3 get current time without creating new object

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I get the current number of milliseconds since midnight January 1, 1970 in AS3 without having to use the 'new' operator? I'm asking because I need to do this about 100 times per second and currently try to reduce heap allocations to keep gc low.

Comment: Is it really needed 100 times per second ?

Comment: The Date class seems to have a set methods for milliseconds etc, so I would imagine you could manually update it. Not sure if I'd trust flash timers though for that purpose if precision is needed.

Comment: Not sure of your usage, but this topic appears in this discussion on the subject. http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/smooth-movement-independent-from-frame-rate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create it once and then add milliseconds, that passed since that creation with getTimer(); You will also need a helping variable to store your Data creation time;

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _myLittleDate:Date;
        private var _myLittleDateCreationTime:Number;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            _myLittleDate = new Date(); //Our first and only object creation
            _myLittleDateCreationTime = getTimer(); //Store it's creation time
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame); //Check function
        }

        private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void 
        {
            _myLittleDate.time += ( getTimer() - _myLittleDateCreationTime );
            trace(_myLittleDate); //You get valid, refreshed data object here
            _myLittleDateCreationTime = getTimer(); // Don't forget to update your initial time
            //It's accurate since method .getTimer() is accurate itself
            //You can even compare two Data object by creating another and tracing it right here
        }
    }
}
```

If you need just to know what time has passed since last frame, without knowing the day of the week, or a year, you can just use getTimer(); on it's own, it's more efficient

Comment: Hey! this looks good! But I think it will be better to not += miliseconds as this will add a rounding error in each iteration, and instead in each iteration get the original time and getTimer() and calculate the current time from it. Anyway I mark this as correct answer, thanks!

Comment: It's field "time" is number of milliseconds passed from Jan 1, 1970, and when you add something with getTimer(), it automatically recalculates all needed data such as day of the week and so on)

Comment: FYI, `getTimer()` returns an `int` value, not a `Number`.

Answer (score 4):

Util method that I use:

```
// Get time since the epoch and time since the VM was started
private static const dateTime:Number = new Date().time;
private static const dateTimestamp:uint = getTimer();
/**
 * Current time in ms
 */ 
public static function getCurrentTime():Number
{
    return dateTime + (getTimer() - dateTimestamp);
}
```